# How to handle 2 columns which refer same master table with ActiveRecord on Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When one table has 2 columns which refer same master table with ActiveRecord on Rails3

There are tables like below.

```
Depts  
  id 
  dept_name 

Users 
  id 
  dept_id 
  previous_dept_id
```

Users table has two columns which refer Depts table.
How can I get dept_name for each columns?

```
class Dept < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :user 
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :dept 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :dept 
  belongs_to :previous_dept, :class_name => 'Dept', :foreign_key => 'previous_dept_id'
end
```

You should then be able to access the two departments like this:

```
dept_name = user.dept.dept_name
previous_dept_name = user.previous_dept.dept_name
```

It's important to note that your `Dept` model will only find users by the `dept_id` column.  I think you'd have to add a second `has_many` to `Dept` if you needed to find users by their previous dept.  Something like:

```
class Dept < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :user 
  has_many :previous_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'previous_dept_id'
end
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I'm still in problem. "uninitialized constant User::dept" Error occurred at "user.previous_dept.dept_name". I don't know if it is different problem. I'm still trying to solve.

Comment: Your class name is pluralized. It shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured out. Ryan's advice is totally right. I've been making a easy mistake on second error. I had made ':class_name => "user"' not ':class_name => "User"'. Capital matter. That's why it could not be initialized. I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: Frederick's advice is correct as well.  I'd been dealing with controllers all day and didn't catch the pluralization.  The class names for your models should be singular or you may run into other issues later.  `class User < ActiveRecord::Base` and `class Dept < ActiveRecord::Base`.  Then be sure to change any uses like `dept = Depts.find(params[id])` over to `dept = Dept.find(params[id])` and so on.